# Search for string with conditions

Tags: sql, sqlite, mysql

I have table with a name filed which is string. I need to create a sql statement that searches for children to a node without finding the children to the children. Is it possible to use LIKE and some wildcards to accomplish this? You can see some examples below of the results I need to get based on my search string.

Search string is /home
Then the follwing entries should be returned

```
/home/something
/home/somethingElse
but not
/home/something/foo
/home/something/bar
/home/somethingElse/foo
```

but if the search string is /home/something

```
These should be returned
/home/something/foo
/home/something/bar
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using - MySQL, SQL Server, etc?

Comment: I am using SQLite for testing and MySQL for production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT name FROM table
     WHERE name LIKE '/home/%' AND name NOT LIKE '/home/%/%'
```

should filter out anything with second level node under it.

Comment: Thanks, that was kind of obvious, can't understand how I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably search on the number of slashes in addition to the actual keywords.  So the first one would be searching for /home with 1-2 /'s

The second one would be /home/something wtih 2-3 slashes.

I don't have sql up infront of me, but I'll work on some sample code for you.

Edit:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_CountChar] ( @pInput VARCHAR(1000), @pSearchChar CHAR(1) )
RETURNS INT
BEGIN

RETURN (LEN(@pInput) - LEN(REPLACE(@pInput, @pSearchChar, '')))

END
GO
```

This little function will act nicely to count the number of slashes in your strings.

Enjoy

Hope this helps,
Cheers,